# How to change angular data table td element from {{element[column]}} to an input form field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-datatables

So, I have this angular materials data table that is being dynamically populated with columns and data from a json file. I have each row being populated using interpolaton -> `{{element[column]}}` right now inside of a standard `td` element. When I click on a row, I can highlight that specific row, but I want to change the `td` from `{{element[column]}}` to a `form`. So, basically **I want to change that one specific line to a `form` element when a row is clicked on**. I'm not sure how to approach this.

I've tried to use `ngIf` to change between ng-templates, but that changes every single row when I click on the row. I only want to change the html element of the row I specifically clicked on. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I can't actually upload any code due to my companies restrictions, but I can use mock code below to display my issue.

I have

```html
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">

    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element[column]}}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

I want to change the current `td` element when I click on a specific row to a `form` with `input`, but only that specific row, not all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to separate the table and the content. So define a new component representing your cell´s content which on click will transform to a form.

See for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q46mwh